# wkhtmltopdf v-0.11.0 rc1 direct download

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I'm looking for wkhtmltopdf v-0.11.0 rc1

I found only links that are redirecting me to installation tutorials/

Is there way to apply files only without installing this version on my machine?

Or anyone can provide a link to direct file download?